# .htaccess Dynamic Url in Folder or Subfolder

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

what I am looking for

Creating a dynamic SEO friendly URL inside the folder

```
like:
exmple.com/category/product/my-heading-1 or 2 or 3
```

[image]

```
current directory: 
exmple.com/category/
exmple.com/category/product/
```

---

I try with this code but it works only the home page. I am not using MySQL

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)  product.php?u=&1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep your htaccess file in category folder and try following rules once. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Also not sure why you are mentioning product.php its not present in your shown screen shot, so mentioning index.php in rewrite rule here.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?u=&1 [NC,L]
```